# Function to create array of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array with characters such as ["A","P","P","L","E","S","A","R","E"], I'm trying to create a function that will loop over the elements in the array, and create an array for each character, which will then be put into a master array. The master array will end up looking like`[["A"],["P","P"],["L"],["E"],["S"],["A"],["R"],["E"]` at the end, using a comparator function to check values `(a,b) => a == b`. Essentially, it needs to check each successive letter, and if they are the same, group into their own array within the master. The two A's should not be grouped together, since they aren't successive.

```
var arr = ["A","P","P","L","E"];
var master = [];
arr.sort(function(a,b){
   for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++){
     compare each element to its successor. if successor is the same, create array of like elements ["A"],["C","C"],["B"] within final array
     if(i + 1 == i){
       master.push(i);
     }
   }  
});
```

Comment: [tag:homework] is it?

Comment: Haha, no. Haven't had "homework" for many years. Trying something out, but going blank on how to do it.

Comment: Interview coding question -- is it? :-P

Comment: Could be a good one.

Comment: There's no question here, just a work request. If you have a specific question you'd like to ask, ask it.

Comment: `sort` provides no guarantee over which elements it compares. Namely, any sorting algorithm worth its salt will start by comparing elements that are _not_ adjanced.

Comment: `if(i + 1 == i){` will always be false. When would a number be equal to itself plus 1? Maybe some freak fringe case. You don't want to compare i + 1 to i, you want to compare the element at i with the element at i + 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do as follows;

```js
var arr = ["A","P","P","L","E"],
 result = arr.reduce((p,c) => {var fi = p.findIndex(a => a[0] === c);
                               fi === -1 ? p.push([c]) : p[fi].push(c);
                               return p;
                              },[]);
console.log(result);
```

As per the grouping only the sequential duplicates the following should do;

```js
var      arr = ["A","P","P","L","E","S","A","R","E"],
stickTheSame = a => a.reduce((p,c) => (p[p.length-1][0] === void 0 ||
                                       p[p.length-1][0] === c      ? p[p.length-1].push(c)
                                                                   : p.push([c]),
                                       p),[[]]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(stickTheSame(arr)));
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it lumps non successive like characters together. So if you had ["A","P","P","L","E","A","R","E"], it would combine the two A's together. It should only combine if they are next to each other and similar.

Comment: The issue here is that it has to be from one large array, not broken into two.

Comment: @user3438917 I guess the second snippet is doing just what you are asking for.

Comment: I figured it out just as you posted the correct answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the array and compare the last value to the current one.

DO NOT SORT -- that will change the order of your input array!

```js
const coolFn = (arr) => {
    return arr.reduce((rez, value, index) => {
      if (index !== 0 && rez[rez.length - 1][0] === value) {
          rez[rez.length - 1].push(value);
      } else {
        rez.push([value]);
      }
      
      return rez;
    }, []);
}

const rez = coolFn('APPLES ARE NOT A BANANA PUDDING CUP'.split(''));

console.log(rez);
```

Comment: This is close, but needs to run against an array, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

Can be accomplished pretty easily with `Set` to get unique items, `reduce` to turn transform and `filter` to find matching elements:

```js
const arr = ["A","P","P","L","E"]
// get unique keys by expanding to a Set
const letters = [...new Set(arr)].reduce((p, c) => {
   // add all matching elements from original array to aggregate
   p.push(arr.filter(i => i === c))
   return p;
}, []);

console.log(letters);
```

**edit**: sorry, I missed the requirement (hidden in a comment in your code) that you only add by comparing each element to its successor. My solution creates an array of each letter with its number of occurrences

Comment: Why the need for a set?

Comment: Because `coolFn('APPLEP'.split(''));` doesn't work - `Set` gets all the unique options and finds all occurrences of them

Comment: It produces: `[["A"],["P","P"],["L"],["E"],["P"]]`, not `[["A"],["P","P","P"],["L"],["E"]]`

Comment: But the OP only wants if the direct previous is the same letter. `BANANA` sshould return BANANA

Comment: See the OP `compare each element to its successor. if successor is the same, create array of like elements ["A"],["C","C"],["B"] within final array`

Comment: Ahhhh, missed that comment in the code example. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Happy to help! :-)

Comment: The issue with this is that if you have an array like ["A","P","P","L","E","A","R","E"], it'll group the A's as well. Letters without successive like characters shouldn't be grouped.